# Joomla - mod_articles_latest not showing latest

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

I've tried searching around on the site and google with no luck so here goes;

In joomla, using the module mod_articles_latest, what could be the reason for it not showing the latest news? I get 4 news as i requested and i told it to choose by dated published yet it seems that it doesn't update when i add a new article to the category i told it to use.

I'm thinking cache might be the reason but i i have it turned off for the module.

Using joomla 2.5.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Would you give us the settings which you have done in this module (Featured Articles, Order, Category)?

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure you haven't modify any files of mod_articles_latest. If you have modified then revert it n check. Second Check the list of articles & their published date. Even if it doesn't work then there are lots of free module which shows the list of latest articles on Joomla extension site. If you have half an hour & you know how to built Joomla module, you can proceed. At the end mod_articles_latest modules works perfectly for me. Thanks

Comment: Since it is used on the webpage of a customer, the template comes with an override for the default view, however it is basically a copy of the original, only with a div or two applied for styling ;) But will take a look at the things mentioned :) Writing a custome module seems a bit much when the default one is meant to do fine

Comment: Interestingly it appears to sort "latest news" based on ID in reverse order, so lowest ID gets picked first, what sort of madness is this :P Oh well, seems i'll be switching to latest news enhanced, thanks anyway!